# Querying data by boolean fields on Parse Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform, boolean, cloud

I`m trying to retrieve some rows using Parse Cloud Code Query.

Normaly, to compare field values, you would bind them using the **.equalTo**() and the **.notEqualTo**() methods, which work fine for comparing strings and numbers.

But I can't seem to have them work with booleans.

On my query no matter if I change ...

```
storesQuery.equalTo('is_open', false);
```

... to ...

```
storesQuery.notEqualTo('is_open', false);
```

I always get the same results. And I have data with both true and false values.

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Sorry I pasted the wrong code bit. Please note the first method call is .equalTo(), while the second is .notEqualTo()

Comment: Do you mean true in one example and false in the other?  The two snippets shown here are identical.

Comment: I made a mistake but it wasnt the value passed, but the name of the method. Thanks for noticing.